# Prove that all meromorphic bijections are Möbius transformations

Tags: complex-analysis

With the notation $\overline{\mathbb C}= \mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$, I want to show that every meromorphic bijection $f:\overline{\mathbb C}\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb C}$ is a Möbius transformation.  A Mobius transformation is any

$$ \frac{az+b}{cz+d} , \quad a,b,c,d\in\mathbb C$$

with $ad-bc\ne 0$.  I have that the meromorphic functions in $\overline {\mathbb C}$ are the rational functions.  I can see that, because $f$ is rational then it has a partial fraction decomposition.  But so does $z^2$ and that's a rational function ... so I can guess that somehow the assumption of being bijective comes in right about now.  And somehow it should tell us that the maximum degree of the numerator and denominator is 1.

I'm also guessing that somehow I should first inspect the poles and argue that the largest order of any pole is 1, and then make some kind of argument about $f(1/z)$.

---

So ok, to make an attempt on some of these guesses: $f$ has the form

$$ f(z) = {P(z)\over Q(z)} $$

If $\deg P \geq \deg Q$ then we can perform long division  to separate this into

$$ {P(z)\over Q(z)} = R(z)+{S(z)\over Q(z)} $$

Where $R$ and $S$ are polynomials and $\deg S < \deg Q$.  I'm not sure why the degree of $R$ should have to be 0 but it seems like it must, because I'm guessing we'll turn the ${S(z)\over Q(z)}$ into a sum of polynomials in $1/(z-z_k)$ for the $z_k$ roots of $Q$.  Then with each of these being a Mobius transformation, we want to argue that their sum is a Möbius transformation ...

Well, I'm actually now unsure that their sum is a Möbius transformation now that I think of it.  Maybe this whole path was a giant dead-end.  Should I be trying to do something entirely different from partial fractions?

Comment: Composing with a Möbius transformation you can assume that $f(\infty) \ne 0,\infty$, then $f(z)=P(z)/Q(z)$ where $P,Q$ have no common root and the same degree, the roots of $P$ are $f^{-1}(0)$ and the roots of $Q$ are $f^{-1}(\infty)$. So $f$ bijective implies $f(z)=(z-a)^n/(z-b)^n$. Finally $s\to s^n$ is bijective iff $n=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compose any such bijection $\varphi:\overline{\mathbb C}\to\overline{\mathbb C}$ with a Möbius transformation $\mu$ to get a meromorphic bijection mapping $\infty\mapsto\infty$. Restricting to $\mathbb C$, this is an entire bijection $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, with a pole at $\infty$. The pole at $\infty$ makes it a polynomial, and bijective polynomials are exactly the linear ones, which are Möbius transformations. So $\varphi\circ\mu$ is a Möbius transformation. And since Möbius transformations are a group under composition, $\varphi$ is one, too.

Comment: Wait, how do we know any such bijection can be composed some Mobius transformation to get a meromorphic function mapping infinity to infinity?  At first read I thought we would find $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=L$ and set $\mu(z) = \frac{1}{1-L}$.  But how are we guaranteed that $L$ exists?  We know $f$ goes to infinity along some path, but how do we know it goes to infinity (or any other fixed value) along all paths?

Comment: @Addem: Existence of $L$ is guaranteed because as functions to $\overline{\mathbb C}$, meromorphic functions are continuous. But anyway, you don't need to consider any limits. $\varphi$ maps $\overline{\mathbb C}$ to $\overline{\mathbb C}$, so $\varphi(\infty)=:L$ exists by definition. Also, you want $\mu(z)=\frac{1}{z-L}$, but I suppose that was just a typo. And also, if that's what you choose for $\mu$, you have to compose like $\mu\circ\varphi$. To compose $\varphi\circ\mu$ like I did, you should choose $\mu(z)=\frac{Mz+1}{z}$, where $M:=\varphi^{-1}(\infty)$.